# Gearman (perl extension): Send message from worker to client

Tags: perl, gearman

I'm working on a distributed job execution system with gearman (perl extension). When the work retrieves a foreground job, I hope the client could get the hostname of the worker's machine, which requires a methodology sending message from worker to client. I think it's possible because we already have `Gearman::Job->set_status` method, which however could only deal with numerical values. I did some research and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7982450/gearman-sending-data-from-a-background-worker-to-the-client), but it's for Gearman PHP extensions. Do we have some similar method for Perl?

Comment: https://metacpan.org/release/Gearman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<del>At last I found that even thought we don't get a `send_data` in Gearman::Worker package on CPAN, there exists another package `Gearman::XS::Worker` which provides [this function](http://search.cpan.org/~dschoen/Gearman-XS-0.12/lib/Gearman/XS/Job.pm#%24job-%3Esend_data%28%24data%29), and will do the trick.</del>

EDIT: I tried `Gearman::XS::Worker` but it seems some methods don't work with my Gearman 0.33. So I went back to `Gearman::Worker`, and added `send_data` method to this package according to gearman's protocol, you can clone it [here](https://github.com/duskast/Gearman) (clone the repo and override the Gearman directory).